# Saving data with the hive package

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

How can I save and retrieve this map using hive?:

```
Map<DateTime, List<PressureModel>> pressures = {
DateTime(2023, 1, 11): [
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '144 / 64 - 74', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 11, 8, 45)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '157 / 64 - 77', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 11, 20, 8)),
],
DateTime(2023, 1, 12): [
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '146 / 71 - 92', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 12, 7, 46))
],
DateTime(2023, 1, 14): [
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '132 / 68 - 74', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 14, 10, 45)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '141 / 53 - 83', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 14, 21, 14)),
],
DateTime(2023, 1, 15): [
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '124 / 52 - 62', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 15, 10, 26)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '134 / 62 - 91', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 15, 18, 57)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '153 / 68 - 85', date: DateTime(2023, 1, 15, 21, 18)),
]};
```

This is what the PressureModel class looks like:

```
class PressureModel {
  String pressure;
  String action;
  DateTime date;

  PressureModel({required this.pressure, this.action = '', required this.date});
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT-generated content is banned on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH, What does ChatGPT have to do with this?

Comment: You posted a ChatGPT-generated solution in an edit to your question. Aside from answers not belonging in questions, ChatGPT content is disallowed here, in both answers and questions.